# Quick action for Account, hide some fields

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, quickaction

I created a quick action for Account (lightning experience). Its target object is task, and it's showing up under activity. There are some fields which I would like to hide, like status, priority and assigned to. When I drag them up to remove from the layout I get this error:

> These fields aren't on this layout, but must have a value to save
>   successfully. Either add them to the layout, or provide a default
>   value.

How can I hide these fields without getting an error. If I need to provide them default values how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the message because those fields are mandatory. If you want to hide, set the pre-defined value for them.

**Set Predefined Field Values for Quick Action Fields**

When you create actions, use predefined field values to set a value for a field. Predefined values can help ensure consistency and make it faster and easier for users to create records.

> If you set predefined values for fields on object records created
>   through an action, you don’t need to add those fields to the action
>   layout.

For example, when you configure an action that lets users create opportunities, set Prospecting as the predefined value for the Stage field. All new opportunities users create through that action are automatically assigned to the prospecting stage. You can remove the Stage field from the action’s layout, because the field is going to be assigned a value automatically.

[image]

> Predefined values for fields on actions are different from default
>   values that you can set for fields on records. If a field is included
>   in an action, it can have both a predefined value set for the action
>   and a default value set.

Steps to follow:-

1. Click the name of an action in the Buttons, Links, and Actions list
   or the Global Actions list.
2. On the action detail page, click New in the Predefined Field Values
   list. Select the field you want to predefine a value for.
3. Specify the value for the field.
4. For single-select picklists, you can specify both a specific value
   and a formula value. If you set both, the formula value takes
   precedence over the specific value.
5. Click Save.

> On object-specific actions, the predefined value can include
>   references to the source object and its related objects.

You would like to see:- [Notes on Predefined Field Values for Quick Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values_notes.htm&type=5)

Reference:- [Set Predefined Field Values for Quick Action Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know for assigned to what is the right predefined value? Honestly if it's hard to set that to the user it can be set to any random value or blank.